# select special rows from feature using condition in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, delete, error-000229

I am using ModelBuilder and would like to delete specific rows of a feature where the value of two columns are equal.

For instance: if there are columns a,b,c,d and rows 1,2,3,4. I would like to delete the rows where a=c. For that, it is first needed to select those features. When I enter the syntax in the query builder a = c I receive error (000229) and it does't work. I have tried another selection method (Make feature Layer, Selection by Attribute) I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

[image]

Comment: Rather than deleting features I think you will find it much easier to just use the Select tool to create a new feature class with only the features that you did not want to delete i.e. those where `a <> c`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedbcak. I have tried that approach but it does not work. It can not recognise when I say a = c. I recieve error 000229 which means can not open the feature. I am assuming for defining the columns we have to úse sth else but I am not sure how.

Comment: My question is abit different as I donot define specific value in the column but I ask all the rows where to value of the columns of them are equal.

Comment: I just tested and it worked for me.  I recommend editing your question to show exactly how you tried to run the Select tool.  Make sure that you use the expression builder to get the syntax correct.  My expression with shapefiles was `"Field1" <> "Field2"`.

Comment: You do not seem to have tried the Select (Analysis) tool as recommended in the most upvoted answer in the duplicate.

Comment: I just tried the Select (Analysis) tool as recommended  and got the same result and have added a screenshot of the result above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52361/discussion-between-user2355306-and-polygeo).

Comment: I am at work and here unfortunately the chat part is filtered

Comment: Is your background processing turned on?  "When background processing is turned on, scripts execute using 64-bit background processing. ArcMap is unable to read data types not supported by 64-bit background processing, while tools incapable of running in the background cannot leverage 64-bit processing. By default, ArcMap and ArcCatalog communicate through a 32-bit client library." http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012177

Comment: @artwork21 It looks like your comment has the content necessary to write an answer that the asker would accept.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment noted, "When background processing is turned on, scripts execute using 64-bit background processing. ArcMap is unable to read data types not supported by 64-bit background processing, while tools incapable of running in the background cannot leverage 64-bit processing. By default, ArcMap and ArcCatalog communicate through a 32-bit client library."

[support.esri.com/technical-article/000012177](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012177)